# Change the index structure of fields in a table in database? Wise thing to do?

Tags: 7, database

I'm on Drupal 7. The table index structure of `users` table is shown in the fig below:

[image: snap]
As pointed out the table has two unique keys `uid`(also primary) and `name` which is the username of the user of the site. The username is displayed on the top of the user's profile.

- I want the `mail` column to be unique, and make it non-nullable.
- and remove the unique characteristics of `name`;

Because username can be same (my use case) and e-mail id shouldn't repeat.
Is it safe to make the change? If not what precautions do I need to take?

Comment: My general thinking is as follows:  *Did Drupal do this to my database?  I'd best leave it alone.*

Comment: Somewhat related question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4777/is-adding-indexes-to-a-drupal-database-safe

Comment: @Chapabu yes, obviously *Drupal did this to my database*. But, I was thinking about the effects(adverse) it could have if I change it. I think I'll try that on my local and test it for some time and then take my decision

Comment: @MPD thanks for the link! It helped me clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are even thinking about doing this I have two big key phrases

- BACKUPS
- DEV SERVER

Here is what you should do

- Install MySQL on a DevServer
- mysqldump the database and load it on the DevServer
- Point your Drupal App at the DevServer and bang on it, and kick the tires

Once you got a good dev environment, now do this on the DevServer

```
SELECT mail,COUNT(1) MailCount FROM users
GROUP BY mail HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

If you get any rows coming back, there are multiple users using the same `mail` value

If nothing comes back, you can proceed as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users_new LIKE users;
ALTER TABLE users_new DROP INDEX `name`;
ALTER TABLE users_new DROP INDEX `mail`;
ALTER TABLE users_new ADD INDEX `name`;
ALTER TABLE users_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX `mail`;
INSERT INTO users_new SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT COUNT(1) UsersCount FROM users;
SELECT COUNT(1) UsersNewCount FROM users_new;
```

If `UsersCount` = `UsersNewCount`, CONGRATULATIONS, you can continue.

```
ALTER TABLE users RENAME users_old;
ALTER TABLE users_new RENAME users;
```

You drop `users_old` if you are sure you no longer need.

Give it a Try !!!